# What do I do with this zip file? Hired a web developer for a landing page- No instructions were provided

Tags: javascript, css, html, squarespace

StackOverflowers,

I hired a web developer to create a landing page. He did an excellent job in terms of the aesthetics of the page itself.

However, no further communication was provided in regards to having the page actually go live.

Context:
A zip file was provided of the html page he created. So I have the file. Now, what do I do with it to have it go live?

I have hosting+domain on squarespace, and it seems as though its a little difficult to implement via squarespace unless developer mode is accessed- this is way beyond me at the moment.

Also, is there a way to have the new landing page point to my current domain through separate hosting? example: my domain is example.com, is it possible to get this landing page on bluehost and have it directed to example.com/landingpage ?

The solution? How to implement this zip file and have it be a live landing page? Get a godaddy domain + bluehosting...then what? :\

Thanks for reading!

Comment: if you have a domain and a hosting, unzip the file, and upload via FTP the contents.

Comment: or ... upload the zip file to the host and unzip on the host

Comment: Can all this be done just through bluehost?

Comment: Potentially, but it's more reliable and easier to use FTP

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is obtain an FTP (File Transfer Protocol) application for your operating system, then using your credentials you obtained when you bought the website, unzip the file and upload it.

Your file must be named `index.html` for it to be displayed with just your domain as the URL. (e.g. `example.com` is the same as `example.com/index.html`)

FTP applications:

[Fetch](http://fetchsoftworks.com/fetch/download/) (Mac)
[FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org) (Max)

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) (MS Windows)
[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io) (Both)